# Is it fair to say Cohagen's rebel problems were his own doing?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, total-recall

Near the end of the 1990 film [Total Recall](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/), after Quato's Martian rebellion is found and wiped out (except for Melina), Quaid is brought to Cohagen who explains why he went to the trouble of creating Quaid's personality:

> **Cohagen**: You see Quaid, none of our people could ever get close to Quato. The f***ing mutants could always sniff us out.

However, earlier in the film it was established the reason Mars had a mutant population in the first place is because Cohagen made the domes they live under from cheap materials that failed to keep out the more harmful UV radiation.

> **Melina**: The first settlers are buried here. They worked themselves to death but Cohagen ended up with all the money. He built cheap domes and watched their kids turn into freaks.
>
> **Quaid**: I saw them.
>
> **Benny**: And if you want to breathe, you have to buy his air.

Seems to me that if Cohagen hadn't skimped on the domes and began extorting money for air he wouldn't have a rebellion on his hands to begin with, let alone mutant-psychic rebels. Is it out of line to say this was a whole "*Could've avoided this*" plot?

Comment: Not my DV, but I think your question is (at best) opinion-based. Aren't there many scripts using this trick based upon greed and attitude of superiority? Any villain will do that one way or another. Look at the Harkonnen/Fremen (Dune) relationship for instance. And many others I can't think of right now. It doesn't really matter if the plot is weakened by the facts, greed is one of the most powerful desire in human history, and has been used and used again to write books and make movies. "*The world has enough for everyone's needs, but not everyone's greed.*" Mahatma Gandhi.

Comment: In addition to the other comment about greed being popular for motivating characters in stories, this kind of thing happens in real life all the time. Some people are short-sighted, selfish, and cruel, and that’s why sometimes they do things that are to their short-term benefit but then cause them more problems in the long term.

Comment: Well, if only rich assholes weren't rich assholes, people wouldn't be so pissed at them. But alas, c'est la vie. ;-)

Comment: Of course all bad guys could just be good ones and avoid creating troubles. But they _are_ bad ones.

Comment: The story is told by an unreliable narrator (Quaid's memories, which could have been implanted at Rekall), so I have doubts that this question can be answered in a definitive way.